# Not receiving push messages after a hosting hotspot device reconnects its data

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My Android app is using firebase messaging to present data.
When the phone that is running the app is connected through hotspot to a second phone, and that second phone disconnects and reconnects its data, the phone running the app stops receiving messages with firebase messaging.

Detailed steps to reproduce this issue:

1. Open hotspot with phone#2(host) and connect phone#1(app) to it
2. Verify phone#1(app) receives messages through Firebase Messaging
3. On phone#2(host), disable network data.
4. On phone#2(host), enable network data - to restore internet connectivity.
5. Verify that phone#1(app) has regular internet access.
6. Phone#1(app) does not receive messages with Firebase Messaging.

Has anyone encountered this issue? I wasn't able to find anything related besides this similar issue, however i doubt its related - 
https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/619314-fixed-mobile-tethering-not-working.html

Any help as to what's wrong and suggestions on what can i do to prevent losing the ability to receive messages?

Thanks!